# What is the difference between p and a?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

What is the difference between `p` and `a` in C?

```
float a[10],*p; p=a;
```

Comment: `a` is an array of ten floats. `p` is a pointer to its first element. You can find this in any C textbook.

Comment: so a is not a pointer to the first element of the array?

Comment: The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusing. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) does an excellent job of explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

If we define "difference" as the result of subtraction, there answer is *zero*:

```
assert((p-a) == 0);
```

...until you assign some other pointer value to `p` (which you cannot do with `a`, because it doesn't name a pointer variable: it names an array which *decays* to pointer in appropriate contexts; there *are* other contexts, e.g. `sizeof(p)!=sizeof(a)`).

Comment: I vote for the funniest answer of the day!

Comment: if const pointer a stores the adress of the first element of the array and pointer p stores the adress of the pointer a, they both represent the first element of the array?

Answer (score 2):

```
float a[10],*p; p=a;
```

`a` is an array 10 of `float`.

`p` is a pointer to `float`. It points to the first element of `a`.

In C arrays are not pointers. Arrays and pointers are two different types. For example:

```
sizeof a;   // compute the size of an array
sizeof p;   // compute the size of a pointer

p = &a[1];  // this is valid, p points to the second element of a
a = &p[1];  // this is not valid, you cannot assign to an array
```